# Why do we declare an extra variable when pattern matching in c#

Tags: c#, switch-statement, pattern-matching

In C# pattern matching, we have to do this:

```
switch(someVar)
{
  case var x when condition:
    break;
  default:
    break;
}
```

As you can see, we have to declare a new variable whenever we use pattern matching. Why is that? Why can we not use `someVar` directly?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I don't know why you guys are doing that

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch#-pattern-matching-with-the-switch-statement , as you can see in those exemple sometype we need to check if `someVar` is from a specific type. And some time you just want to use the `when` part and don't need extra type validation, but the syntax require it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could use `someVar` directly, like this:

```
switch(someVar)
{
  case var _ when someVar > 10:
    break;
  default:
    break;
}
```

You still need `var _` though, because that's a *pattern*, and switch statements match against *patterns*, not *conditions*. The `_` pattern matches anything. Then the `when ...` part gets checked.